# Limit the queryset of entries displayed for a django admin Inline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

In django admin, using django 1.2, i'm trying to add a InlineModelAdmin to apply a comment on save when a change is made to an entry. (An entry is expected to have a "ChangeComment" for every edit).

I don't want to show previous entries, so I am trying to force the *ChangeCommentInline*'s formset.queryset to be empty, by creating **NoCommentsInlineFormset** and assigning the formset in my **ChangeCommentInline**, but is still returning existing entries.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/forms/modelforms/#changing-the-queryset

Note - In the link above they use *BaseModelFormset*, I'm using *BaseInlineFormset*, which I expect may be the issue.  If I swap out *BaseInlineFormset* with *BaseModelFormset* I get an error about "instance" not existing.

**admin.py**

```
class NoCommentsInlineFormset(models.BaseInlineFormset):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NoCommentsInlineFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.queryset = ChangeComment.objects.none()


class ChangeCommentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = ChangeComment
    extra = 1
    exclude = ("user", )
    formset = NoCommentsInlineFormset

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        """auto-assign logined in user to comment"""
        if not change:
            obj.user = request.user
        obj.save()    


class EntryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):   
    inlines = (ChangeCommentInline, )
```

Can limiting the ChangeComment entries displayed in the Inline be done, or is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: Have a look at BaseModelAdmin:

    def queryset(self, request):
        """
        Returns a QuerySet of all model instances that can be edited by the
        admin site. This is used by changelist_view.
        """

Comment: ...what you need to do is to overwrite the queryset method on your InlineModelAdmin.

Comment: ok, I'll give it a try. thanks! (go ahead and add it as an answer if you want more rep)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As benjaoming mentioned in the comments, it was necessary to override the `get_queryset()` method in the `InlineModelAdmin`. It was not necessary to override and attach a new formset to the `InlineModelAdmin` definition as I initially thought.

Here is the resulting implementation:

```
class ChangeCommentInline(admin.StackedInline):
    """For allowing logged in user to add change comment"""
    model = ChangeComment
    extra = 1
    exclude = ("user", ) # auto-update user field in save_formset method of parent modeladmin.


    def get_queryset(self, request):
        """Alter the queryset to return no existing entries"""
        # get the existing query set, then empty it.
        qs = super(ChangeCommentInline, self).get_queryset(request)
        return qs.none()
```

Comment: It should be noted that as of Django 1.6 the `queryset()` methods is called `get_queryset()`.

Comment: @GregoryGoltsov agreed: fixed. Before Django 1.6 the method was called `queryset()`.

Answer (score 3):

I am supposing you are using a

```
models.ForeignKey(EntryAdmin)
```

in your ChangeComment model. but if you want only one comment for each EntryAdmin, your should use instead a:

```
models.OneToOneField(EntryAdmin)
```

And you won't need your NoCommentsInlineFormset nor your inline class.
That's what I would do.

EDITED

Ok then if you want to keep a history of comments, you could override the queryset in the NoCommentsInlineFormset
as:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(NoCommentsInlineFormset, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.queryset = ChangeComment.objects.order_by('-created_at')[:1]
```

This should work.

Comment: I'm trying to have a "comment" for *each* edit of the given ForeignKey Entry, and maintain that comment history.  So if 5 changes were made, there would be 5 ChangeComment entries in the db, one for each edit.  If I changed it to a OneToOneField wouldn't it only allow a single comment per entry?

Comment: Yes. I think then the simpler solution would be to override the queryset of your form and make something like I did in my edited answer.

Comment: I tried to override the queryset as you mentioned, but I got the error, "queryset" not callable.  Turns out the queryset *method* in the InlineModelAdmin needed to be overridden.