# Django admin readonly for existing field but allowing to add new inline if you click + Add another

Tags: django, admin, inline, readonly

I know, that question was asked but it is not clear to me.

I have put all fields 'readonly field' for `Essai_TemperatureInline`.

I would like to add new Inline in the admin for records not created by current user.

How to do if I want to add new records?

```
class Essai_TemperatureInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Essai_Temperature
    extra = 5
    ordering = ('choix__name', 'choix__lapropriete',)

    def get_readonly_fields(self, request, obj=None):
        if request.user.is_superuser == False:
            notBelongToMe = Material.objects.exclude(user=request.user)
            jj = 0
            if obj:
                while jj < len(notBelongToMe):
                    if notBelongToMe[jj] == obj:
                        return self.readonly_fields + (
                            'name',
                            'nature_unit',
                            'choix',
                            'valT',
                            'val10',
                            'val_ref',
                        )
                    jj += 1

    return self.readonly_fields

class MaterialAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = (MediaInline, UniteProperty2Inline, Essai_TemperatureInline)
```

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, you can't. At least not in a nice way, trough Python, as you would expect if you know [how to do it with regular ModelAdmin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343535/django-admin-make-a-field-read-only-when-modifying-obj-but-required-when-adding). It's a bug in the admin, documented in [Ticket #15602](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/15602)

What you can do is make use of JavaScript. Use this selector:

```
.inline-group tr.has_original
```

The `has_original` class is applied to every inline that represents an already-saved model instance.

So, in the `Essai_TemperatureInline` class, make all your fields editable (non-readonly), and then use JS (jQuery, I guess) to make some of the fields readonly:

```
django.jQuery('.inline-group tr.has_original #id_somefield').attr('readonly', 'readonly');
```

---

See [The Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-asset-definitions) about how to add your own JS to admin pages. Basically:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        css = {
            "all": ("my_styles.css",)
        }
        js = ("my_code.js",)
```

---

#### security note:

This can obviously easily be tricked over, with Firebug or similar browser tool. So make sure to take that into account if necessary, and do some checks, probably somewhere on `formset.clean()`

Comment: If I could find a tutorial for inline-group that would be fine. inline-group tr.has_original is probably in a file (for example) 'addline.js' in a class Media inside Essai_TemperatureInline

Comment: @user3172700 sorry, what? :) I don't get what you mean.

Comment: How to do that ? :class Essai_TemperatureInline(admin.TabularInline):
model = Essai_Temperature

class Media:
      js = ['static/js/jquery-1.7.2.js',
            '/static/js/addline.js',]

Comment: @user3172700 I think that's correct, see my updated answer. I would put it on the `ModelAdmin`, just to be sure, though it should work on the `Inline` class as well.

Comment: the difficulty is how to transcribe with javascript "Material.objects.exclude(user=request.user)" ? with .inline-group tr.has_original

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow, what do you mean by "transcribe with JS". If you'd like to filter what objects appear in the `Inline` then a custom `queryset()` method is what you're after, see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6741937/236195). But that's a separate question.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not really care if the field is read only but you only need to prevent users from changing it, I have found a [workaround](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46676942/2996101):

In the clean method of the inline modelform raise a vailidation error:

```
class Essai_TemperatureForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def clean(self):
        if self.has_changed() and self.initial:
            raise ValidationError(
                'You cannot change this inline',
                code='Forbidden'
            )
        return super().clean()

    class Meta(object):
    model = Essai_Temperature
    fields='__all__'
```