# Django 2.0 autocomplete field, how to prevent the foreign key mapping from being changed, but allow editing

Tags: django, django-admin

In Django 2.0, the Admin introduces an auto complete field. It works great but I can't seem to figure out a way to prevent the user from changing the foreign key object that is mapped in, without making it read only. If I make it read only the foreign key object is not editable using the edit button.

Any suggestions?

Comment: It is not really clear to me what you want to be able to edit, and what not. The foreign key and/or the object values to which it refers?

Comment: In the clean method of the modelform, you may raise a vailidation error if the relevant field is changed.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/46680590/2996101